# Reactjs slider(carousel) with multiple slides in a page

Tags: reactjs, slider, swiper.js

I want to use a slider like this in my react project using swiper library. This has multiple slides so that the center slide is higher than the side slides. I don't know which setting should be used.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cM1XH.png)

Answer (score 0):

play with `depth` attribute to get your desire output.

```
coverflowEffect={{
      rotate: 0,
      depth: 500,
      modifier: 1,
      slideShadows: true
    }}
```

here is the full code example [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/swiper-stackoverflow-example-q55ft?file=/src/App.js:722-846)